# Pasar una clase como parametro a un List<> en Java

Tags: java, hibernate

La función seria algo como esto:

```
private static String ejemplo(String clase) {
    //...
    List<clase> clases = query.list();
    //...
}
```

El problema es que no usa el parametro recibido para darle nombre a la clase. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Ya investigaste sobre **metodos genericos** en java?

Comment: Si, intento documentarme antes de formular una pregunta. Sin embargo no he logrado encontrar algo similar. Se supone que en <clase> debiese ir una clase que ya este en el programa, pero como es un método que ocupo en 10 clases intento volverlo genérico para solo tener que llamarlo en lugar de instanciar la secuencia completa cada vez o realizar sobrecarga.

Comment: facilmente puedo agregarte una respuesta donde tu metodo estatico `ejemplo` lo convierto en generico. (`query.list()` donde list() tbn debe ser generico). Pero aun asi no contestaria o no resolveria lo que quieres hacer. **Primero**: porque el fragmento de codigo que colocaste no da mucha infomacion y **Segundo**: en tu comentario anterior has expandido tu pregunta. Te recomiendo que edites la pregunta agregando datos adicionales y coloques el codigo de lo que tienes hasta el momento. Y quizas debas reorganzar lo que quieres a un repositorio para las consultas.

Comment: Es que en si, lo unico que pregunto es una forma en que clase se pase como parametro al list. Ejemplo: clase contiene la palabra Usuario, entonces List seria List<Usuario>. Asi no tengo que hacer un metodo para cada clase donde lo unico que cambio es el contenido del List<>.

Comment: Bueno si es necesario pasar la clase como parametro, entonces descarta lo que te comente sobre los generico. Lo que puedes hacer es validar el parametro clase en varios `if` o lo que necesites o mejor aun dentro de un `switch` y dependiendo de lo que contenga el parametro clase haces las consulta especifica. al final tendras que manipular el list con una lista de objectos o dividir cada consulta por separado.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar lo siguiente:

```
private static String ejemplo(String clase) {
    //...
    String fullPathOfTheClass = "full.path.to.the.class." + clase
    Class cls = Class.forName(fullPathOfTheClass);        
    Object myTestObject = cls.newInstance();
    List<Object> clases = query.list();
    //When accessing the objects you will need to do a casting

    MyClass myClassSample = (MyClass) clases.get(0);
    //...
}
```

Es importante hacer notar que si lo que pretendes es hacer listas con objetos que pueden variar, a lo mejor tu lógica tiene algún problema. Lo otro que podrías intentar tomando en cuenta que al parecer ocupas hibernate es crear una lista de un `Map<String,Object>` que es lo que por lo regular regresa hibernate

Comment: Excelente tu respuesta, aun asi no le resuelves el `query.list()`, ya que el metodo `ejemplo` sabe que nesecita devolver pero, `query.list()` no lo sabe.

Answer (score 0):

En un primer paso, necesitarías que query.list() devolviera una lista del tipo que quieres, lo que se puede conseguir usando genéricos si tu versión de Hibernate lo soporta:

```
Query<MyClass> query = session.createQuery("<query", MyClass.class)
```

Por tanto, podrías tener algo como

```java
List<E> ejemplo(String q, Class<E> c) {
    Query<E> query=session.createQuery(q,c);
    return query.list();
}


List<MyClass> lista = ejemplo("select m from MyClass m", MyClass.class);
```